# how to change direction of value list in combo box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a combo box with some values that I get from a web service. When I click the combo, and I see the list, I want to see the list's items in right, not in left direction. I used text-align:right and direction:rtl, but they did not help.
here is my css code and asp.net for the combo.

```
.cmboxSecond {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 47px;
    left: 380px;
    font-family: 'B Nazanin';
    direction: rtl;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="cmboxFirst" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CssClass="cmboxSecond " EnableFilterSearch="true" EnableIncrementalSearch="true"  FilterType="StartsWith" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbox_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" ItemInsertLocation="Append"></ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

Comment: Did you try the CSS transform attribute? ```transform: translateX(100%)``` may help you

Comment: @AliRezaBeigy It did not worked

Comment: can you provide small a sample project and add it to your description?